# Create Date Table With Prescription Amount for Every Day in a Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to develop a query to determine the amount of a drug that an individual has had for every day during a quarter.  On some days, there are no drugs prescribed, for others, there may be overlap and I need a total amount (meaning, strength for each summed for a day).  The number of drugs, strengths, daysupply etc. can vary.  Here's some data:

```
create table #MemberInfo 
(ProgramName varchar(255), 
DateFilled datetime, 
DaySupply integer, 
MemberID varchar(255), 
Strength integer, 
Tradename varchar(255));

insert into #MemberInfo
Values ('InsureCo', '20130612', 30, 'MEM001', 10, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130429', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM001', 30, 'Sedative')
```

I really have no idea what the best approach might be to add up the amount of drugs taken on a given day during a quarter.  I'd like to avoid using cursors if I can.  I was thinking about creating a temp table with all the days for a quarter and then somehow joining those dates to every day a drug is taken (i.e., DateFilled + every subsequent day up to DaySupply).  Once I get to the point where I have the dates and amounts for every drug in a quarter, I could group by day and get a sum of strength for each day.  I also need to be able to get the average amount taken over a quarter.

Additional Requirements:

1. I have a start date and a number of days. I'd like to create a row
   for each member for every day they have a prescription (and do the
   same for all of their prescriptions). I would then sum the strength
   of all the drugs for each day. If it helps any, all of the drugs
   will be of the same class, and strength is going to be equivalent
   doses, meaning that I can sum them up.
2. For reporting, I need to be able to count consecutive days that the
   amount is greater than some cutoff (let's say 100). That's why I'm
   trying to get amount per day.

   ```
   Desired output

   MemberID    Date        SumStrength
   MEM001     2013-04-29  40
   MEM001     2013-04-30  40
   MEM001     2013-05-01  20
   ETC FOR EVERY DAY FOR THIS MEMBER

   MEM002     2013-04-01  60
   MEM002     2013-04-02  40
   ETC FOR EVERY DAY FOR THIS MEMBER
   ```

Comment: This is an excellent start to a question here. Now all that's missing is the sample output you'd like to obtain from your sample data and an effort to actually retrieve that output yourself, and we can try and help you find an answer.

Comment: I added some brief sample output to my original question.  Thanks in advance.  This is a little more involved than most of the queries I've written in the past.

Comment: I've removed the `medical` tag as irrelevant. Your issue is not specifically medical, because it has to do merely with amounts and dates.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple group by I think.

```
create table #MemberInfo 
(ProgramName varchar(255), 
DateFilled datetime, 
DaySupply integer, 
MemberID varchar(255), 
Strength integer, 
Tradename varchar(255));

insert into #MemberInfo
Values ('InsureCo', '20130612', 30, 'MEM001', 10, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130429', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130429', 30, 'MEM002', 25, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130515', 30, 'MEM002', 25, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM001', 30, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM003', 35, 'Sedative')
, ('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM003', 45, 'Sedative')

select memberid,datefilled,SUM(strength) as [Strength sum]
from #MemberInfo
where memberid = 'MEM003' -- or whatever, could be a parameter
group by memberid,DateFilled

order by Memberid,DateFilled

drop table #MemberInfo
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't have every day that the drug is filled.  I have a start date and a number of days.  I'd like to create a row for each member for every day they have a prescription (and do the same for all of their prescriptions).  I would then sum the strength of all the drugs for each day.  If it helps any, all of the drugs will be of the same class, and strength is going to be equivalent doses, meaning that I can sum them up.

Comment: @KennyG: You keep adding to the requirements in each answer that people give you. Instead of doing that, [edit] your question so that people know **exactly what your requirements are** when they try and post the answer. We can't hit a moving target.

Comment: @KennyG: ...when we can't predict its next move.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it can be done building a Calendar using a `CTE` and doing the aggregates using `OVER(PARTION BY)`

**Query:**

```
-- Declare a Start and End Date required to build a calendar
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATETIME = '2015-01-01'

-- Build out a Day/Quarter Calendar
;WITH Calendar ([Date], [Quarter]) AS (
    SELECT @StartDate, 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Date] + 1, (DATEDIFF(m, @StartDate, [Date] + 1) / 3) + 1
    FROM Calendar 
    WHERE [Date] + 1 < @EndDate
)

-- Build Result Set
SELECT  ProgramName, 
        DateFilled, 
        DaySupply, 
        MemberID, 
        Strength,
        Quarter,
        SUM(Strength) OVER(PARTITION BY ProgramName, DaySupply, MemberID, Quarter) AS QuarterlyTotal,
        AVG(Strength) OVER(PARTITION BY ProgramName, DaySupply, MemberID, Quarter) AS QuarterlyAverage
FROM #MemberInfo MI
JOIN Calendar C ON MI.DateFilled = C.[Date]
ORDER BY MemberID, DateFilled
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

**Test Data:**

```
create table #MemberInfo 
(ProgramName varchar(255), 
DateFilled datetime, 
DaySupply integer, 
MemberID varchar(255), 
Strength integer, 
Tradename varchar(255));

INSERT INTO #MemberInfo
Values
    --MEM001
    --Q1
     ('InsureCo', '20130112', 30, 'MEM001', 10, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130129', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
    --Q2
    ,('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM001', 30, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130429', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM001', 20, 'Sedative')
    --Q3
    ,('InsureCo', '20130829', 30, 'MEM001', 30, 'Sedative')

    --MEM002
    --Q1
    ,('InsureCo', '20130112', 30, 'MEM002', 10, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130129', 30, 'MEM002', 20, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM002', 20, 'Sedative')
    --Q2
    ,('InsureCo', '20130529', 30, 'MEM002', 30, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130429', 30, 'MEM002', 20, 'Sedative')
    ,('InsureCo', '20130401', 30, 'MEM002', 20, 'Sedative')
    --Q3
    ,('InsureCo', '20130829', 30, 'MEM002', 30, 'Sedative')
    --Q4
    ,('InsureCo', '20131129', 30, 'MEM002', 30, 'Sedative')
```

---

**Result:**

```
ProgramName DateFilled  DaySupply   MemberID    Strength    Quarter QuarterlyTotal  QuarterlyAverage
InsureCo    2013-01-12  30          MEM001      10          1       30              15
InsureCo    2013-01-29  30          MEM001      20          1       30              15
InsureCo    2013-04-01  30          MEM001      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-04-01  30          MEM001      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-04-29  30          MEM001      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-05-29  30          MEM001      30          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-08-29  30          MEM001      30          3       30              30
InsureCo    2013-01-12  30          MEM002      10          1       30              15
InsureCo    2013-01-29  30          MEM002      20          1       30              15
InsureCo    2013-04-01  30          MEM002      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-04-01  30          MEM002      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-04-29  30          MEM002      20          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-05-29  30          MEM002      30          2       90              22
InsureCo    2013-08-29  30          MEM002      30          3       30              30
InsureCo    2013-11-29  30          MEM002      30          4       30              30
```

Comment: This works for the quarterly average.  For reporting, I need to be able to count consecutive days that the amount is greater than some cutoff (let's say 100).  That's why I'm trying to get amount per day.

Comment: @KennyG: See my comment to Jerry's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145340/create-date-table-with-prescription-amount-for-every-day-in-a-quarter?noredirect=1#comment28319084_19145940

Answer (score 0):

I've done some playing around tonight and I'm much closer:

Some data:

```
create TABLE dateranges (drug VARCHAR(5), date_begin DATETIME, numdays integer,strength        integer)
INSERT into dateranges values ('DrugA', '2010-01-01', 5, 10);
INSERT into dateranges values ('DrugB', '2008-02-27', 10, 20);
INSERT into dateranges values ('DrugC', '2010-04-26', 3, 20);
INSERT into dateranges values ('DrugD', '2000-02-01', 5, 30);
```

A CTE:

```
WITH cte (id, d, s)
     AS (SELECT tbl.drug AS id
                ,tbl.date_begin AS d
                ,tbl.strength AS s
           FROM dateranges tbl
          WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, tbl.date_begin, tbl.date_begin+numdays-1) <= 100
         UNION ALL
         SELECT tbl.drug AS id
                ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.d) AS d
                ,tbl.strength as s
           FROM cte
                INNER JOIN dateranges tbl
                  ON cte.id = tbl.drug
          WHERE cte.d < tbl.date_begin+numdays-1)
SELECT id AS drug
       ,d AS dates
       ,s AS strength
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY id, d, s
```

Results:

```
DRUG    DATES   STRENGTH
DrugA   January, 01 2010 00:00:00+0000  10
DrugA   January, 02 2010 00:00:00+0000  10
DrugA   January, 03 2010 00:00:00+0000  10
DrugA   January, 04 2010 00:00:00+0000  10
DrugA   January, 05 2010 00:00:00+0000  10
DrugB   February, 27 2008 00:00:00+0000 20
DrugB   February, 28 2008 00:00:00+0000 20
DrugB   February, 29 2008 00:00:00+0000 20
DrugB   March, 01 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 02 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 03 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 04 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 05 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 06 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugB   March, 07 2008 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugC   April, 26 2010 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugC   April, 27 2010 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugC   April, 28 2010 00:00:00+0000    20
DrugD   February, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 30
DrugD   February, 02 2000 00:00:00+0000 30
DrugD   February, 03 2000 00:00:00+0000 30
DrugD   February, 04 2000 00:00:00+0000 30
DrugD   February, 05 2000 00:00:00+0000 30
```

From here, I plan on grouping by drug, date, strength (summing strength).  I should be able to toss those results into a temp table, and then count the number of days over the threshold I mentioned.